# Can not start Java Web Start on a protected site

Tags: java, web-applications, java-web-start, saml

I have the following problem.  In one server, I have a folder  /protected/ that requires authentication using a SAML token.

When I try to access resources in this folder, I get redirected to a log-in page first, and after login I can access the resource.

Now, I added a .jnlp file inside the /protected/ folder with all resources required.  When I try to access the .jnlp file, I get the login page as expected.  After logging in Java Web Start initializes and tries to download the resources.

However, Smart Start fails immediately, complaining that it couldn't parse the .jnlp file.  When I look into the debug console, I see that Java downloaded, instead of the jnlp file, the log-in page.  So it seems that the Java Web Start application does not share the credentials of the browser, so it requires a new log-in

My identity provider is ZXID, and we are using SAML.  I would assume that Java Web Start must somehow use the same SAML token as the browser, right?  Is this correct? is it possible?

So far in my investigations, it seems that when the browser finds a .jnlp file, it starts Java immediately and the Java Application will try to download the jnlp, creating this issue.  I did find out that the JNLP file must not contain the codebase entry.  Otherwise the Java VM will try to re-download the file, but because it is not authenticated it will get the login page.

However, if the JNLP can be read, the resources can not be in the protected area either, because again JWS is not authenticated.

So I guess what is needed is that the JWS VM somehow gets the session id from the browser, so it is considered Authenticated.

Any ideas?

Comment: _Tentative:_ Maybe using a Keystore with JWS helps (web search). Otherwise you maybe need an unprotected loader (JNLP/applet/JS) that does its own URLConnection to initiate the origial JNLP download. Magic for me.

Comment: Maybe a link URL-rewritten as "xyz.JNLP?JSESSION_ID=..."?

Answer (score 1):

So far, I haven't found a proper solution to this problem.  I did the following, and it worked:

- Created a protected area on my server, and added a servlet behind it
- My servlet creates a JNLP file on the fly, with a session id.
- JNLP file is used to download the JARs from a public location
- The session id is used by the web start application to load resources from the protected area.